# Mouse cursor does not change until processes are finished

Tags: jquery, css, process, mouse, loading

I want to change the cursor type to 'wait' during some simple jQuery operations (no ajax).

But the css change only takes effect after all operations are done.

e.g.:

```
$('body').css('cursor', 'wait');
for (i = 0; i < 999999999; i++) {
    //do some operations
}
// change cursor back after operation
$('body').css('cursor', '');
```

If you execute this, you will not see the cursor change. (At least not in Chrome).

One solution would be to put the code after the first css change into a SetInterval function, but that is not a very nice way and not acceptable in my context.

Do you know a way how to solve this problem?

Comment: The issue is because JS is single threaded. Therefore it cannot update the UI until the mammoth `for` loop has finished. As you've stated, the solution would be to use a timer to branch the logic. For what reason do you need such a huge loop?

Comment: It is actually not such a big loop. (I just made it simple to just explain the problem)
Im doing a lot of data parsing. Which could be compared to a mammoth 'for' loop.

I guess I will have to work with SetInterval then.

Thanks for the fast reply!

Comment: No problem. If you're still having issues I'd suggest posting a new question using your actual code - or a simplified version of it. There may still be alternative ways to achieve what you require.